# Having a platformed game level in a storyboard

Tags: cocoa-touch, storyboard

I was wondering how in Games when the character goes forward the screen moves with them and the level continues on, past the extent of a storyboard (Like the background is longer then the storyboard. Does anyone know how? (Not using a game engine)

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering how in Games when the character goes forward the screen moves with them and the level continues on, past the extent of a storyboard

The objects on the game board generally aren't laid out in a storyboard file. The view that *is* the game board could certainly be part of the storyboard, but the content that that view draws is typically generated by the game's code. For example, it's common to use a sprite framework like SpriteKit or Cocos2D to draw objects using sprites. The data that the game manages is the collection of objects that appear in the game, and a sprite might be used to represent each of those objects.

Consider a platform jumping game like Doodle Jump, where the player hops from one platform to the next. The platforms keep coming and coming and coming as long as the player doesn't fall. Those platforms aren't laid out visually in the storyboard editor. Instead, a list of platform positions is somehow generated -- they could be read from a file, or calculated using some function, or create by some algorithm. A sprite is created for each platform as needed to fill the screen, and probably destroyed after it scrolls off the screen.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. Do you know any references that teach this?

Comment: Check out http://www.raywenderlich.com.  They have dozens of tutorials on just this topic.

Comment: There are LOTS of books on iOS games programming, and many more on games programming generally. Also lots of web sites, tutorials, etc. Try googling "iOS games programming" to get started. Agree with WeekendCodeWarrior that raywenderlich.com is a good resource, but there are many others. Follow your nose.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help to end this post off Cocos2D Version 2 works with xcode5?

Comment: Well, Cocos2D is up to version 3 now, and they [recommend using the latest version of Xcode](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/getting-started/).